# ms-coherence in matlab and python

Tags: python, matlab

I'm analyzing `ms-coherence` between two signals, and I'm comparing the results of `scipy.signal.coherence` with Matlab's `mscohere` function. I'm not getting the same result when I use the same parameters in both functions:

Matlab

```
x = [1,3,5,7,4,6,7,8,9,3,5,6]
y = [3,4,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,1,5,6]

[cxy,w] = mscohere(x,y,hann(6),3,6,1)

cxy =
    0.7489
    0.6034
    0.2813
    0.3319

w =
         0
    0.1667
    0.3333
    0.5000
```

Python

```
from scipy.signal import coherence
x = [1,3,5,7,4,6,7,8,9,3,5,6]
y = [3,4,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,1,5,6]

coherence(x,y,'hann',noverlap=3,nperseg=6,fs=1,detrend=False)

(array([0.        , 0.16666667, 0.33333333, 0.5       ]),
 array([0.76762535, 0.53185638, 0.32743784, 0.07759385]))
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the SciPy 'hann' window is the periodic Hanning window. Not much of a difference for longer data series, but for this example with tiny series, the difference is considerable.

```
[cxy,w] = mscohere(x,y,hann(6,'periodic'),3,6,1)

 cxy =
    0.7676
    0.5319
    0.3274
    0.0776
w =
         0
    0.1667
    0.3333
    0.5000
```

Now the results between Matlab and SciPy agree.

Answer (score 0):

The inner algorithms boths are different's, i degug both codes and i could perceive differences.
Bellow you see difference using the same parameters in scipy.signal.coherence and Matlab's mscohere.

Follow some details dafault parameters matlab:

```
# %   When WINDOW and NOVERLAP are not specified, MSCOHERE divides X into
# %   eight sections with 50% overlap and windows each section with a Hamming
# %   window. MSCOHERE computes and averages the periodogram of each section
# %   to produce the estimate.
# L = fix(M./4.5);  noverlap = fix(0.5.*L); options.nfft = max(256,2^nextpow2(N));
#k = (M-noverlap)./(L-noverlap);
#m= n_sample L = int( n_sample // 4.5 ) noverlap= n/2
```

Follow example python using same parameters matlab

```
 L = int( n_sample // 4.5 )
 nfft = max( 256, 2 ** math.ceil( math.log2( L ) ) )
 frequences, coherence = signal.coherence(mean_zero_left, mean_zero_rigth, fs=self._fa, nfft=nfft, window=signal.get_window('hamming', L, fftbins=False), noverlap=int(L//2))
```

This manner you see the graph comparing both result
[comparing Python x Matlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXIVf.png)

I recomend to use matplotlib.mlab.cohere have the same algorithm matlab, but the number of point fft (nfft) have validation equals a niquist theorem.

```
coherence2 = mlab.cohere(mean_zero_left, mean_zero_rigth, window=np.hamming(L), NFFT=nfft, noverlap=int(L//2), Fs=self._fa)
```